# Replace the string in a file in Unix - replace the part of the matching regular expression

Tags: json, unix, sed, jq

I have a JSON document with such a repeating structure

```
{"version":"21.0.0.1","artifact":"artifact","payload":[{"id":"ng-at-ng/at","name":"ng/at","location":"apmservices/at:21.3.0.2-linux-amd64","component":"core","tag":"21.3.0.2-linux-amd64"},{"id":"doi-dspintegrator-doi/dspintegrator","name":"doi/dspintegrator","location":"doi/1.3.    3/dspintegrator:2.0.0-RELEASE_183","component":"doi","tag":"2.0.0-RELEASE_183"}]}
```

I want to replace the value of all `"location"` tags with `-` wherever there is a `/`. So after the replacement, the above text becomes:

```
{"version":"21.0.0.1","artifact":"artifact","payload":[{"id":"ng-at-ng/at","name":"ng/at","location":"apmservices-at:21.3.0.2-linux-amd64","component":"core","tag":"21.3.0.2-linux-amd64"}, {"id":"doi-dspintegrator-doi/dspintegrator","name":"doi/dspintegrator","location":"doi-1.3.3-dspintegrator:2.0.0-RELEASE_183","component":"doi","tag":"2.0.0-RELEASE_183"}]}
```

Note that there can be multiple `/` and `-` in the value of `"location"` tags in the original JSON document.

Reading through some other posts, it appears that `-E` option in `sed` with capture should be used but I am not sure how to make it work. Please can someone help?

Comment: Can you solve a simpler problem? Can you change `"abcabc":"a/b/c"` to `"abcabc":"a-b-c"`?

Comment: If it is only one occurrence, then I can. But there are multiple occurrences of location key so not sure how to restrict any regex to just capture that part.

Comment: Do you know how to use `t` to perform the same substitution over and over?

Comment: My problem is how to write a regex so that it matches all location keys one at a time. When I use ```\"location\":\".*\",```, this finds the first occurrence of ```location``` and matches up to the last occurrence of ```",``` in the file.

Comment: `sed` is not well-suited to this kind of task in general.  In general, non-trivial processing of JSON is best done with a JSON-aware language or module or tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq):

```
.payload[].location |= gsub("/";"-")
```

Or, if you want every "location" key checked, irrespective of where the key occurs:

```
walk(if type == "object" and (.location|type=="string") 
     then .location |= gsub("/";"-") else . end)
```